# Fix 'cors' request between different localhosts. 405 (Method Not Allowed)

Tags: javascript, http, cors, fetch

I use the following code to request the file:

```
function getData(imageEndpoint) {
  return fetch(imageEndpoint, {
    mode: 'cors'
  })
    .then(response => {
      console.log(response);
    })
    .then(data => {
      if (!('caches' in window)) {
        return caches.open(cacheName)
        .then(cache => {
          return cache.put(imageEndpoint, data);
        });
      }
      return data;
    })
    .catch(e => {
      console.log('Request issue, ', e);
    });
}
```

Which outputs in following error message:

```
Failed to load http://localhost:7000/image.jpg: No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource. Origin 'http://localhost:8080' is therefore not allowed access. If an opaque response serves your needs, set the request's mode to 'no-cors' to fetch the resource with CORS disabled.
```

P.S The server works on `:8000`

When I add cors header

```
  return fetch(imageEndpoint, {
    mode: 'cors',
    headers: {
      'Access-Control-Allow-Origin': '*'
    }
  })
```

The following error is beeing thrown:

```
http://localhost:7000/image.jpg 405 (Method Not Allowed)

index.html:1 Failed to load http://localhost:7000/image.jpg: Response to preflight request doesn't pass access control check: No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource. Origin 'http://localhost:8080' is therefore not allowed access. The response had HTTP status code 405. If an opaque response serves your needs, set the request's mode to 'no-cors' to fetch the resource with CORS disabled.
```

Can you please suggest how the request should be setup in order succesfully receive the file?

Answer (score 0):

you need to have the header Access-Control-Allow-Origin: `URL Here` or Access-Control-Allow-Origin: * on both the OPTIONS response and the POST response. You should include the header Access-Control-Allow-Credentials: true on the POST response as well.

Your OPTIONS response should also include the header Access-Control-Allow-Headers: origin, content-type, accept to match the requested header.

Comment: URL here should I replace it with the target server url, or with the one from where I am sending the request?

Comment: `https ://domain:port`